# How to console.log a short message every 3 hours on express js server?

Tags: node.js, express, notifications

I have an easy express js server. I need it to check database for upcoming meetings and console.log in terminal remind message 2 hours before the meeting. How can i do this?

```
const start = () => {
    let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    try {
        DBconnect()
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('server is running on port' + PORT)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

I tried to do make setInterval to check database for upcoming meetings, but i seemed to use wrong so the app kind of stops when i try something like this

```
const start = () => {
    let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    try {
        DBconnect()
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('server is running on port' + PORT)
        })
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('bla bla')
        }, THREE_HOURS)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, I would suggest you use a cron job instead of `setInterval`. There are NPM modules for creating cron jobs. You can use this one named [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

**Usage:**

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob(
    '0 */3 * * *', // Every three hours
    function() {
        console.log('You will see this message every three hours');
    },
    null,
    true
);
```